# Flutter - How to rotate a 3D object along Y axis?

Tags: flutter, animation, 3d

[image]

So it's a 3D object that's rotating 360 degrees.
What I want is that the instead of rotating along the X-axis, it should rotate along the Y-axis. Also, the current anchor point is at the center of the screen (the feet of the astronaut). I want to change it to be the center of the object.

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage>
with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
late Object astronaut;
late final AnimationController _controller;
@override
void initState() {
_controller = AnimationController(
  vsync: this,
  duration: Duration(seconds: 10),
)..repeat();
astronaut = Object(fileName: 'assets/mercedes/Astronaut.obj');
super.initState();
}

void dispose() {
 _controller.dispose();

 super.dispose();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('3D Demo'),
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
  ),
  // body:

  body: Center(
    child: AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _controller,
      builder: (_, child) {
        return Transform.rotate(
          angle: _controller.value * 2 * math.pi,
          child: child,
        );
      },
      child: Cube(
        onSceneCreated: (Scene scene) {
          scene.world.add(astronaut);
          scene.camera.zoom = 10;
         },
       ),
     ),
   ),
 );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can rotate x axis, y axis and z axis.

```
return Transform(
            transform: Matrix4.identity()
              ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.01)
              ..rotateX(
                math.pi * 0 * _Controller.value, //change 0 to any value to rotate x Axis
              )
              ..rotateY(
                math.pi * 2 * _Controller.value,
              )
              ..rotateZ(
                math.pi * 0 * _Controller.value, //change 0 to any value to rotate z Axis
              ),
            child: child,
            
          );
```

Comment: This does not rotate it, its giving it another animation, kind of the object coming from top left and disappearing in the bottom right.

Comment: I believe you need to rotate the z axis, not the y axis. To get the result you're looking for, change the 0 in rotateZ to 2 (or any other value you want), and replace the 2 in rotateY with 0.

Comment: I have got it rotating along the Y axis but the problem is, it's rotating like a 2D object. It's already a 3D object. I guess this code is for rotating 2D stuff. Btw, Alignment: Alignment.center is missing in your code.